# Multiple password encrypt/protect a single file

Tags: api, encryption, zip, rar

This one is tough to Google. I'm trying to find a solution or API to encrypt/protect a file with multiple passwords. The passwords would be handed out to users separately.

I looked at DotNetZip and the usual Zip and Rar solutions (including PKWare) for a way to multi-password protect a file.

All suggestions are welcome! I wouldn't be posting this question if it was either impossible or uncommon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use passphrase-based OpenPGP encryption. It lets you specify several independent passphrases and supports compression. [OpenPGPBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pgp.php) package of our SecureBlackbox product does this (among a number of other features) and it's available for .NET, Java and VCL.

Comment: Please add some invocation examples (for GnuPG for example) as I am unable to figure out how to do this.

Comment: @chx SecureBlackbox includes plenty of samples in the downloadable version.